# How do I get the length of elements of each json file in directory containing several jsons

Tags: arrays, dictionary, merge, jq, element

I have a directory with only json files each having a minimum of atleast 1 element

```
foo.json
bar.json
baz.json
```

I want to create a new json array with above json files which I am able to with following:

```
ls | jq -R '{name: split("\\n") | .[]}' | jq -s '.'
```

which results as:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo.json"
  },
  {
    "name": "bar.json"
  },
  {
    "name": "baz.json"
  }
]
```

But what I need is length of the corresponding elements respective to each of the json file along with the name as below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "foo.json",
    "size": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "bar.json",
    "size": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "baz.json",
    "size": 15
  }
]
```

This command gives only size of the json without any mapping to the actual filename

```
jq -s 'map(length) ' ./*.json
```

like:

```
[
  5,
  10,
  15
]
```

Any pointers to have the two commands merged and evolved in better way to get the expected output as mentioned above would be much appreciated

Tried adding size to each element through

```
ls | jq -R '{name: split("\\n"), size: map(length) | .[]}'
```

But is resulting in error in iterating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `input_filename` to get the file name:

```
jq -n '[inputs | { name: input_filename, size: length }]' *.json
```

Comment: Thanks much @Philippe. Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is not suitable for parsing. Instead, you could iterate over all of the files directly within one call to jq, for example using `inputs`, and get each filename using `input_filename`. For example:

```bash
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $in ([]; . + [{
  name: input_filename,
  size: $in | length
}])' *.json
```

Comment: Thanks again @pmf. This also works perfectly to what I wanted, had to accept Philippe's answer as it came first. Much appreciated though